# Reduce time of a drone log to a single record per second

Tags: qgis, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, video

I am trying to use the log track that come from the dji phantom, after convert into csv and being able to import in QGIS, I get a table with  10 records per second. This is beacuse it gives me one record per 100 milisecond. For what I need which is export to a gpx file to use in another software, I want to delete or average this 10 records per second into one record.

[image]

My Goal in doing all this is beacause I want to use the video and the tracklog from the drone dji phantom4 to be able to use in the plug in UAV tracker for QGIS or use VIRB EDIT..

I know this can Be done easly in Dashware but I dont want to use that sofware, I really need the UAV tracker, I have made I worked but is such a pain to clean the data so I will work...  Anybody have a better way to get the UAV working for dji phantom without so much prep?

[image]

Comment: Please do not use all-caps in question titles (it drives away potential answers)

Answer (score 1):

Try to select records where the modulo (remainder after division) of time over 1000 is zero (e.g. time % 1000 = 0),
then invert the selection and erase those rows. Don't forget to toggle editing before erasing.
[image]